# Better clustering results with non-normalized data than with normalization applied

Tags: r, clustering

I'm working on a uni assignment and for this I need to do clustering on the dataset containing gene expression levels for 1867 genes for 72 patients.

The diagnosis of leukaemia type is included with the dataset so my goal is to produce a clustering solution that can correctly cluster patients to respective leukaemia types.

Expression levels of various genes have very different ranges and so the first idea I had is that I need to normalise the data. Here's the example of data:

```
> head(leukemia_dat[,8:15])
  Gene_6 Gene_7 Gene_8 Gene_9 Gene_10 Gene_11 Gene_12 Gene_13
1     10    165     10    215   14538    9738    8529      70
2     37     18     10    116     615     115    1518     153
3    183    238    104    476    5669    3272    3668      66
4     45    247     10    155    4850    2293    2569      10
5     10     44     10    122    1284    2731     316      78
6     65     39     10    176    4148    2743    2404      10
```

I used k-means algorithm to create clustering but with this scaled data the resulting solution is far from perfect:

```
          Reference
Prediction ALL AML
       ALL  38  25
       AML   9   0
```

What is strange is that if I remove scaling or normalization of any kind and use raw data I get a much better result:

```
          Reference
Prediction ALL AML
       ALL  47   8
       AML   0  17
```

I do want to use the clustering solution without scaling since it produces a better result but not exactly sure how to properly justify the selection or if it is a right approach at all.

Comment: Why do you use clustering when you have labeled data? Maybe try logistic regression?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, the idea of the exercise was to see whether it is possible to cluster the data in such a way that it would correlate with known labels.